# Query to output data from multiple days

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select count(distinct orderid), employeeinfo.Name
from orderinfo, employeeinfo
where preparedate = '2014-11-10'
and prepareby = employeeid
group by employeeinfo.name
```

It outputs data like

```
1  |  Jeff
4  |  Bob
5  |  Steve
```

Is there a way to make this work for a date range so that I can graph the data in excel?

if I want to line graph data for every day for the month of December

Comment: What is the expected output, could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what's your expected output, but to get a date range, you could use:

```
select count(distinct orderid), employeeinfo.Name
from orderinfo, employeeinfo
where preparedate <= '2014-11-30' AND preparedate >= '2014-11-01'
and prepareby = employeeid
group by employeeinfo.name
```